# Unwanted padding left margin of images using CSS wrapper

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I have unwanted padding on the left of images (see code below).  I have tried changing, deleting or substituting every line of code in the CSS .wrapper-shadow -- no luck.  This error appears in Firefox, Chrome and Explorer.  Interestingly, I have very similar code for tablet and mobile pages for the same site which do not have the error.  I tried substituting the tablet CSS and HTML for the desktop code and the error showed up anyway.   [See attached image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iQwL.jpg).

Also interesting:  The tablet and mobile sites (which display correctly) have narrower left margins than the desktop site. [See attached image of margin difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnQbg.jpg). I searched through every line of my custom bootstrap CSS to see if I could find a difference between the desktop and tablet style sheets -- again, no luck.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.
Zaffer

```css
.wrapper_shadow{ 
 max-width: 765px;
 background-color: #9ebade;
 border: thin solid #758fa9;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px #758fa9;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 2px #758fa9;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding-left: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="pageHeaderText">Virtual performance art made with Unity3D game creation software</div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
       <div class="wrapper_shadow center-block">
         <img src="images/ColorCubed_765.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="ColorCubed"/>
      </div>
```

Comment: What does the `img-responsive center-block` rules do/look like?

Comment: @LGSon http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer myself.  It's wonderful how thinking about a question enough to post it sometimes makes the answer pop up in your brain a few minutes later.

I had the line: "padding-left: 5px;" in the *{} style of my parent bootstrap.css which was cascading down and causing the error in my styles.css.  (See code below).  The fact that the error was appearing only in the desktop version of my site and not in the tablet or mobile, which have their own stylesheets was the clue.  I guess the moral of the story is always to check your cascades.  Thanks.
Zaffer

```css
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
```